# Polar plot using pgfplots>polaraxis in Plain Tex

Tags: pgfplots, plain-tex, polarplot

I use polaraxis a lot in the pgfplots package. It works well in LaTex. However, in Plain Tex I get an error like the following:

```
! Undefined control sequence. \pgfplots@environment@polaraxis@
[#1]->\begin 
            {axis}[#1,data cs=polar,axis t... l.10 ylabel = Permeability]
```

I have not been able to resolve it searching all over the web. It seems that there are not many people using both Plain Tex and polaraxis. Any help or suggest would be much appreciated!

```
\input miniltx
\input graphicx.sty
\input tikz
\input pgfplots
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\tikzpicture
\polaraxis
[xlabel=Angle from RD ($^\circ$), 
ylabel = Permeability]

\addplot+ [domain=0:3] (360*x,x); % (angle,radius)
\endpolaraxis
\endtikzpicture
```

Comment: Also in plain TeX you need braces, `xlabel=Angle from RD {$^\circ$},`.

Comment: the brackets are not for grouping but normal texts. Also it does not resolve the issue to change the brackets to braces.

Comment: Sorry to hear that but LaTeX the parser gets confused by just adding parentheses. Unfortunately I do not know enough about plain TeX, in particular about `miniltx`, and it seems that on my updated TeXLive2020 installation I cannot run `tex` anymore...

Answer (score 1):

This appears fixed in current releases, if I add `\bye` to the posted code with texlive 2020 pdftex I get

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, David. You are right. I updated my TexLive to the latest version. It is working now.